# Backup Exec 2012 will not backup Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, backupexec

Backup Exec 2012 SP3 is unable to 'see' Sharepoint 2010 installed on the same server for backing up. MSSQL 2008, Symantec Backup Exec 2012, Sharepoint 2010 are all installed on same server. Agent for Application and Databases has also been purchased but Backup Exec cannot browse to Sharepoint Farm. Sharepoint Farm account has local admin privileges and so does Backup Exec service account. MSSQL Server databases are being backup properly using the Backup Exec service account. I'm not sure how to troublshoot if this is an account issue or an agent issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a different agent to backup that. Read up on symantec best practice ( http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=HOWTO74431).

Answer (score -1):

Check through the list on this document to verif the permissions have been setup appropriately  http://www.symantec.com/docs/TECH75907